# ANT permission denied while installation

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, ant, chmod

I'm very new to this so I think it's a basic doubt. I am trying to install ANT on ubuntu I am running on wsl. I'm not able to unzip the folder to usr/local because it's showing a permission error.

When i try to unzip the folder I get this error:

```
user@user:~$ unzip apache-ant-1.9.16-bin.zip -d /usr/local/

checkdir error:  cannot create /usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.16
                 Permission denied
```

I tried this to grant permissions, but it doesn't seem to solve the problem:

```
sudo chmod -R u+w /usr/local
```